# Robocopy logfile (not showing missed/failed files)

Tags: robocopy

I'm having trouble getting this to work properly, I'm trying to copy every file from an external HDD to my NAS device, and i only wanted to see in the logfile what are the files that have been skipped or not copied, this is what i used after reading on the forums:

```
Robocopy E:\ "\\NAS" /e /v /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /ns /nc /np /log+:"C:\Users\xx\Desktop\log.txt"
```

For some reason, it doesn't save anything to the logfile when it's done, completely empty. Yet when i check the file and folder properties of both HDD and the Backup folder it shows that there are over 50,000 files that have NOT been copied.

Comment: Does `[your_command] >> "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\log.txt"` works by any chance? It might be a permission issue.

Comment: Same thing, creates an empty text file.

Comment: By the way, if i remove "/v /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /ns /nc /np", it does show everything in the text file, but of course i only want to see the errors, not the successful transfers, which will be a lot of lines to check.